# Back-references in JavaScript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

Is there anyway to pick up back-references?

```
var name = "HELLO WORLD"
var patt = /\S+\s(.+)/;
alert(name.match(patt));
```

This is just a simple example to get every word after the first.

But, if I alert `$1`, nothing pops up and I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. How did you try to alert `$1`? Currently you are alerting the match results. More about regular expressions in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I just said alert($1). Would that be incorrect?

Comment: JavaScript is not Perl. When you use regular expressions to replace part of a string, you can use `$1` in the replacement string to refer to the first capture group. In your examples, the result of `.match` is an array if the pattern matches and the second element will contain the content of the first capture group, if that is what you want.

Comment: That was kind of silly. Sorry for the bad question guys.

Looks like I just had to do:

    alert(RegExp.$1);

to get the correct alert.

Comment: Ha, I actually did not know that this works as well :) But anyways, as I said, `.match` returns an array. The first element is the whole match, any other element refers to capture groups (if the regular expression does not have the global modifier). You might also want to have a look at [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). I'd say this is more commonly used than `RegExp.$X`.

Comment: I just saw too many things on google using $1 and then eventually I found one that said that so I tried it and it worked haha. Thanks for the help though, that makes much more sense now. I'm much more used to Ruby/Perl (just really started javascript a week or two ago and never had to try a regex till now). I understand your capture group tip now too :) Thanks! I'll check out exec, thanks again for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick solution to this if anyone is actually looking for this.

You can use `RegExp.$X` where `X` is the digit of the reference you seek. `match` returns an array as well, which you can use to see whether things matched as well as the backreferences in the following indices.